# Get hidden attribute of a model specified using Model::with()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In a controller, I use this code to get all `Text` objects and their associated `authors`

```
return Text::with('authors')->get();
```

This is part of a backend only available to admins, and I need them to be able to access the authors `name` fields. But in the `Author` model, I set `protected $hidden = ['name'];` when I programmed another part of my app that's for standard users.

There's a `hasMany` relationship: Each text has many authors. Is there a way to use `with`, but get some hidden attribute? Or the other way round, to declare some attribute as hidden temporarily when using `with`?

Please note this is question is about the use of `with` in combination with hidden attributes. I'm not looking for something like `$authors = $authors->makeVisible(['name']);` (which is explained [here](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bw5Cc2ABm3E/)).

Comment: Are you returning a JSON response?

Comment: I don't really get your question, my code sample is nothing but a return statement. `get()`. Technically, I thing `get()` returns an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`.

Comment: So you know, `protected $hidden = ['name']` only affects `Author` when it is cast to an array or `JSON`. If it is still an instance of `Author`, you should be able to access `$author->name` without issue. Are you calling `->toArray();` or `return response()->json();` anywhere that would be associated with `$text->authors`? Cause if not, this is a non-issue.

Comment: My controller method consists of this line only. I load the texts and associated data from an AJAX request, so I guess it's some automatic conversion that removes the hidden field. However, it's not available in the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find two approaches to solve my problem:

1) Using `each` as seen in [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/149753)

```
$texts = Text::with('authors')
             ->get()
             ->each(function ($text) {
    $text->authors->makeVisible(['name']);
});
```

2) Using `transform()` as recommended in [an answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/150086) to the same question. This seems to be way faster.

```
$texts = Text::with('authors')
             ->get()
             ->transform(function ($text) {
    $text->authors->makeVisible(['name']);
    return $text;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Text::with(['author'=>function($q){
$q->makeVisible('name')
}])->get();
```

Comment: This does not work in my Laravel 5.8 project: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::makeVisible()`. I edited my question because in my app a `Text` may have multiple `Author`'s, but your code throws an error for `hasOne` relations as well.